# I would like to use { useForm } from "react-hook-form" in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How should I use useForm in classComponent?

The error.

> src/components/projects/CreateProject.js
> Line 40:44:  React Hook "useForm" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
import  {Component ,useState}  from 'react'
import  {connect} from 'react-redux'
import  {createProject , sampleteFunction} from '../../store/actions/projectActions'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class CreateProject extends Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        content: ''
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        //console.log(this.state)
        this.props.createProject(this.state)
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }

   


    render() {

        const { auth } = this.props;
        const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
        
        if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />

        return (
    
            <div className="container">
<form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create a New Project</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" id='title' onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="title">Project Title</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1">Create</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error message is clear enough: you *can't* use hooks inside class components.

Comment: You can't, first you need to rebuild the component to a functional component.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite         this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hooks in a class-based component. But, you can create a HOC, a higher-order functional component, and pass down the form instance to the class-based component. This is not an optimal solution but works if you don't want to rewrite your component.
For example:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function withFormHOC(Component) {
   function UseForm(props) {
     const form = useForm();
     return <Component form={form} {...props} />
   }
   return UseForm
}
```